# changing buildpath in eclipse to recognize path of jsp files in jsp files

Tags: eclipse, jsp-tags, buildpath

I want to built simple maven login page using spring and hibernate in eclipse ide but got struck with the http 404 error. when i run the application in tomcat server index.jsp file loads and when i click the login link it shows http status 404 error. how to make eclipse recognize the path of jsp files. If i mention the path as "N:\java\SpringHibernate\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\login.jsp" it is displaying the content along with tags written in login.jsp file. how to resolve this problem. thanks in advance.
[this is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0nJ1.png)

inde.jsp file

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<body>
 <table align="center">
  <tr>
   <td><a href="/login.jsp">Login</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are trying to bundle up Java EE stuff like jsps, the WTP will help with this. It helps you create a Deployment Descriptor to simulate the war file bundling that would normally happen before deploy.

Comment: You have a runtime error, so how are you going to make this work at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

from the past 2 months i am using eclipse version:oxygen release candidate 2(4.7.0 RC2) with build id:20170601-1219 and i cant be able to solve the issue.
now i have installed version:2018-12(4.10.0) with build id-20181214-0600 and the issue is resolved. The problem is with the eclipse version. So guys use the right version.
Thank you